# main method as final in java

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I saw this code in one of the certification exams:

```
public class SimpleClass 
{
    int num;
    final static void main(final String args[])
    {
        String s1="new";
        String s2="String";
        String s3="Creation";
        System.out.println(s1+s2+s3);
    }
}
```

I  know  that  final  methods  are  ones  which  are  not  possible  to  override.  I  also  know  that  if  the  usual  signature  of  the  `main`  method is  altered,  it  will  be  treated  as  any  other  ordinary  method  by  the JVM, and  not as `main()`.

However,  the  options  given  to me  were:

```
1>  Code  won't  compile
2>  Code  will  throw  an  exception
3>  will  print  newStringCreation.
```

It's  not  possible  to  run  this  program  on  eclipse  IDE.  Can  anyone  explain  what  should  be  the  answer  and  why?

**Ok  let  me  put  my  question  like  this - When  I  execute  my  program, what  will  happen?  Which of the 3 options above  should  I  choose?**

Comment: Nasty question. `final` should not matter. But `main` is also not public, which would worry me.

Comment: Yes, the code will compile, it just won't run.

Comment: Well, define "run"; if this means you launch it with `java SimpleClass` then it will throw an exception, since as you mentioned yourself, there is, in fact, no `main()` to run. Also, you can't override `static` methods in any way, shape or form, so declaring them `final` is redundant.

Comment: @fge Declaring static method **IS NOT** redundant at all. You can hide static methods in subclasses, if you do not declare them as final in superclass.

Comment: Did you try to compile and run this yourself? What do you mean by "It's not possible to run this program on eclipse IDE."? What happens when you try? Did you try to run it on the command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The  Code will compile without any problems but **it will throw a run-time exception saying "main method not public"**. The main method has to be public because it has to be called by JVM which is outside the scope of the package and hence would need the access specifier-public. If you are unable to run it in eclipse, try the archaic method of saving the file in a notepad with filename.java. Go to cmd and reach the file location..If on desktop, use cd desktop! Use the following commands to run the file-

```
javac filename.java

java filename
```

You will see the required run-time exception that I mentioned above.

Comment: I agree with Stefan on his answer, I was unable to give a detailed description as a comment so answered separately. @Gpar, try this method, you might find what you are looking for :)

Comment: Thanks  @hchawla,  I  did  try  your  suggestion,  but  in  cmd  got  the  error  called  "javac  is  not  recognised  as  an  internal  or  external  command".  Please  tell  me  what  should  I  do  next?

Comment: Were you in the same directory in cmd where the file was, when you executed the javac comment?

Comment: @Gpar this link should be helpful to fix such errors, if there are any :)http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html

Answer (score 11):

`final static void main` won't run, since main is not public.

`public final static void main` will work.

At least that's the behavior on my Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 4):

The `main` method has to be accessible from the outside. Hence, in your case the application will compile but throw an execution at runtime.

Comment: If  it  throws  an  exception  than,  what  kind  of  exception  it  might  be?  Sorry I  am  unable  to  execute  the  program  as  it  is  on  Eclipse  IDE.

Answer (score -1):

You have the main method but since the modifier is final JVM wont be able to run the main method of the program.You wont see any compilation error.

You can run the program in eclipse  when you make the modifier change of **final** to **public**

Comment: Main method can be final. It should be public final.